# Count occurrences of an email address in a text file

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a .txt file with many emails including headers. I'm just wondering how I would use perl to find out how many occurrences of the same email address are found in this text file?
Would it involve regular expressions?

Comment: That depends on the structure of your text file. Some more details would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @email_list = ();
my %count;

while (my $line = <>) {
    foreach my $email (split /\s+/, $line) {
        if ( $email =~ /^[-\w.]+@([a-z0-9][a-z-0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/i ) {

            push(@email_list,$email);
        }
    }
}

print "Total Email Count: ".scalar(@email_list)."\n\n";
$count{$_}++ for @email_list;
print Dumper(\%count);
```

Save it to a file such as `email.pl` and make sure it executable `chmod +x email.pl`.

`./email.pl file.txt`

It will print the total number of email addresses found and count per email address.

Comment: This can be a nice quick-and-dirty solution, as long as one is aware (and doesn't mind) that it is far from matching all valid email addresses according to the specification.

Comment: @dan1111 the `OP` spec was very vague and mentioned `regex`, agree it would better to use `Email::Valid` or something but this does the job and *relatively* simple to understand  :)

Comment: thanks for this, how would I execute this if I already have another function in my perl file which also requires the file.txt argument?

Comment: @sudo_o, I agree with your points.  I think this was a useful answer, but just wanted to add some additional information that may be important in some situations.

Answer (score 5):

You might find [cpan: Email::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Email-Find-0.10/lib/Email/Find.pm) useful. You could store the addresses you find in a hash table with email as the key and counter as value. You should be able to do that with the callback. Can you get started with this?

Comment: Another address parsing module - [Regexp::Common::Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/~cwest/Regexp-Common-Email-Address-1.01/lib/Regexp/Common/Email/Address.pm).

Comment: @ChrisCharley marvelous, even better than the one I found!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all email addresses, I recommend trying a module rather than writing your own regex.  Correctly matching all email addresses gets quite complicated.

However, if you simply want to search for a given email address, you can accomplish this with a fairly simple regex:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $email = 'foo@bar.com';

while(<DATA>)
{
    $count++ while (m/(^|\s)\K\Q$email\E(?=\s|$)/g);
}

print "Found $email $count times";

__DATA__
foo@bar.com foo@bar.com

mr-foo@bar.com #not a match

old.foo@bar.com   #not a match
blah blah blah foo@bar.com blah blah
foo@bar.commmm #not a match
```

Note that this requires the email address to be separated from any other content by whitespace.

A couple of notes:
`\Q...\E` is the quote-literal escape.  It ensures that nothing in the email address is treated as special regex characters (Without this, the `.` would match any character rather than a literal period).

`(?=...)` is a look-ahead insertion.  This will match the contents without including it in the actual match.  This is important, because a single space may be *before* one occurrence of the email and *after* another.  In order to match both, you don't want the first match to "eat up" that space.